# UIButton action not triggering on ViewController that is presented modally

Tags: swift, static, uibutton

It's a pretty simple configuration I have.
There's MainController, which will present NewController. Once NewController is presented, the whole UI loads. Some of it is within a UIScrollView, some is static. I have a few UIButtons and a UIBarButtonItem in the Navigation Bar. The UIBarButtonItem functions as expected. However, my UIButtons don't do anything. If you hold down on them, they highlight, but the touchUpInside event does not seem to call my @Objc method.

The thing I don't understand is that at one point, I had NewController pushed instead of presented, and the UIButtons worked fine. Now that it is being presented, they don't work though.

Based on what I've already researched about this issue, it seemed common that the button was being pressed twice as a result of multiple instances of NewController. That is not the case for me though.

MainController presentation method:

```swift
let newController = NewController()
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newController)
navController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

My UIButton and its method in NewController:

```swift
static let star: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star"), for: .normal)
    btn.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "star.fill"), for: .selected)
    btn.setTitle("  Add to Favorites", for: .normal)
    btn.setTitle("  Remove from Favorites", for: .selected)
    btn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: [.normal, .selected])
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.r6whiteAlpha(), for: [.highlighted, .focused])
    btn.tintColor = .white
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(starTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return btn
}()

@objc func starTapped() {
    print("star tapped") // Nothing prints to console.
}
```

Something I should mention is all of the UIButtons I am having problems with are static variables. They are also both inside of the UIScrollView.

UPDATE: I changed my code around to force only one instance of NewController to exist and eliminate the need for a static variables, but it did not change anything.

[image: NewController]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I spent a few more hours on it. After countless attempts and reviewing my code, I found the problem and it is very bizarre.

On MainController, I have a UITextField. Once the return key is pressed, it presents NewController. The keyboard closes and it presents. I did not call `textField.endEditing(true)` before presenting and that seemed to cause my problem for some reason.

Solution:
If you have a UITextField as the first responder, you MUST call `endEditing(true)` before modally presenting another ViewController or you will run into this issue.